# Use same output file name from pipe as input name with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, bash

I'm trying to get the output name to be the same as the input name while using the pipe command in ffmpeg.

The file is called **1-Minute Audio Test for Stereo Speakers & Headphones [2ZrWHtvSog4].m4a**
I'm trying to get the **output filename** to be **automatically** the same as the **input file name** but with the **mp3** extension.

So the final name should be **1-Minute Audio Test for Stereo Speakers & Headphones [2ZrWHtvSog4].mp3** without having to type it in manually.

**Example:**

```
yt-dlp -o - -f 139 --external-downloader aria2c --external-downloader-args '-d ./ -x 10' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZrWHtvSog4 | ffmpeg -i pipe: -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 8000 -ac 1 -ar 8000 test_audio.mp3
```

These commands create a file called **test_audio.mp3** it should be **1-Minute Audio Test for Stereo Speakers & Headphones [2ZrWHtvSog4].mp3**

**I'm not sure how to pipe the name variable from the input file to the output file of ffmpeg.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yt-dlp -o - -f 139 --external-downloader aria2c --external-downloader-args '-d ./ -x 10' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZrWHtvSog4 | ffmpeg -i pipe: -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 8000 -ac 1 -ar 8000 -f mp3 "$(basename "$(yt-dlp -e https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZrWHtvSog4 | sed 's/[\/:*?"<>|]/_/g')").mp3"
```

To use the same output file name from the pipe as the input name with `ffmpeg`, you can modify the command as follows:

```bash
yt-dlp -o - -f 139 --external-downloader aria2c --external-downloader-args '-d ./ -x 10' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZrWHtvSog4 | ffmpeg -i pipe: -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 8000 -ac 1 -ar 8000 -f mp3 "$(basename "$(yt-dlp -e https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZrWHtvSog4 | sed 's/[\/:*?"<>|]/_/g')").mp3"
```

Explanation:

1. The `basename` command is used to extract the base name from the URL. It retrieves the video title using `yt-dlp -e https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZrWHtvSog4` and then replaces any characters that are not allowed in file names with underscores using `sed 's/[\/:*?"<>|]/_/g'`.
2. The `$(...)` syntax is used to execute a command and use its output as part of the larger command.
3. `$(basename "$(yt-dlp -e https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZrWHtvSog4 | sed 's/[\/:*?"<>|]/_/g')").mp3` is the resulting file name with the `.mp3` extension added.

Replace `test_audio.mp3` in your original command with the modified file name expression. This will create an output file with the same name as the video title retrieved from the URL.